# Why did auto-upgrade Lollipop not hit in my Moto G 2nd Gen?

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, motorola-droid, motorola-moto-g

All,I am very excited to look forward to taste Lollipop in my Moto G 2nd, From the [read](http://www.droid-life.com/2014/11/12/motorola-makes-lollipop-update-official-for-moto-g-2nd-gen-and-moto-x-pure-edition/), I was told Moto will auto-upgrade the Android system in their device from 4.4 to 5. I already checked my phone, In the "About Phone" , it shows "Moto G 2nd", But Why the upgrade notice doesn't show .Did I missed something ? Please help me .Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not something that we can answer factually. Other devices (even including Nexus) face the same issue. Whether they decided to skip 5.0 to more stable version or not, only Motorola can answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew ,Thanks your help, So , I should go to the Motorola support forum to get some help. Right ? thanks.

Comment: In this case, it's better... or probably the only way to know the reason. If you feel generous, you could link back the forum post from there so that our community may follow up this issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rollouts are done in stages, so you may not have been selected (automatically) yet.

This could be for a number of reasons:
-The rollout is still in progress
-They have postponed the rollout due to bugs

There are methods that allow you trick the rollout system (they will only work in the first case, not the second), but they aren't guaranteed to work, on my old nexus 4 you could wipe google play services data and reboot, there is probably a motorola equivalent.

Other than that, sit tight, motorola are probably acting in your bests interests (neither of my friends with moto g (2) have receive the update either)

Comment: Found answers in the [Motorola support forum](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/684dda3d86?commentId=862213#862213). It just need more patience. Thank you guys!